# how to use laser scan matcher?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-hydro, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to ROS I have to use the laser_Scan_matcher which I got from github scan_tools. when I do catkin_make

There is a error csm/csm_all.h... I added it by downloading this .h file, again on catkin_make I get another file missing like this I got more than 50 files approximately...and still its files not found errors are increasing as I add each missing file ...Please help me to solve this problem,  what is the exact package files I needed and modifications to be done .

Please help in clear steps how to use a bag file say example 2robots.hospitals bagfile and what will be the output for laser_scan_matcher.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198038/how-to-use-laser-scan-matcher?/) by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2014-11-24**:
What happens when you try the commands [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/197658/errors-at-catkin_make-for-laser_scan_matcher/?answer=197757#post-id-197757)?

**Comment by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on 2014-11-25**:
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'laser_scan_matcher'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(scan_tools-master/laser_scan_matcher)
-- Could NOT find Git (missing:  GIT_EXECUTABLE)
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1060 (message):
error: could not find git for clone of csm_src

**Comment by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on 2014-11-25**:
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1478 (_ep_add_download_command)
scan_tools-master/laser_scan_matcher/csm/GetCSM.cmake:12 (ExternalProject_Add)
scan_tools-master/laser_scan_matcher/CMakeLists.txt:6 (download_and_compile_csm)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-25**:
Do you have git installed?

**Comment by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on 2014-11-26**:
Thank you so much ..I did nt have git-core..I have installed now..I dont have error any more.

**Comment by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on 2014-11-26**:
I can see only the laser_scan_matcher_node in lib/laser_Scan_matcher after catkin_make. How to test this laser scan matcher?

**Comment by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on 2014-11-26**:
$ rosrun laser_scan_matcher laser_scan_matcher_node is executed on bag file running behind in another terminal.. I got [ INFO] []: Starting LaserScanMatcher
what should be the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The original answer was to install git and follow this other answer for installing laser_scan_matcher: http://answers.ros.org/question/197658/errors-at-catkin_make-for-laser_scan_matcher/?answer=197757#post-id-197757

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1